Type @ and get a list of options
I'm working with React and I'm want to create something similar to what modern apps use for their inputs. You type a specific character (@) and a list of options becomes available.
I tried using a div with its property contentEditable, but that seems to have a problem with security. Can you point me towards a practical solution?
